# filter out all tablets on google-play ( no screen compatibility mode)

Tags: android, google-play

regarding to the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps ) you should do:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

but this also filters out handsets with e.g. xxhdpi - unfortunately you cannot add xxhdpi as it is not available as a value: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
supports-screens is also no option as:

> Caution: If you use the  element for the reverse
>   scenario (when your application is not compatible with larger screens)
>   and set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external
>   services such as Google Play do not apply filtering. Your application
>   will still be available to larger screens, but when it runs, it will
>   not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a
>   handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see Screen Compatibility
>   Mode for more information). If you want to prevent your application
>   from being downloaded on larger screens, use , as
>   discussed in the previous section about Declaring an App is Only for
>   Handsets.

another option is to filter for telephony feature - but there are some tablets that have telephony. Is there any way to do this right?

Comment: What is the difference between tablets with telephony feature and handsets that have large screens as tablets?

Comment: the boundraries are fluid - but I know the app atm looks bad on 7''+ - ideally I would like to filter out everything >7''until the layout is optimized for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    ...
    <!-- support for xxhdpi densities -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    ...
    <!-- support for xxhdpi densities -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

As per [the documentation itself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html), you simply put the raw int value for xxhdpi screens:

> Note: This attribute currently does not accept xxhdpi as a valid
>   value, but you can instead specify 480 as the value, which is the
>   approximate threshold for xhdpi screens.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with?

```
<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="500"/>
```

Comment: no - as the documentation states: android:largestWidthLimitDp
This attribute allows you to force-enable screen compatibility mode by specifying the maximum "smallest screen width" for which your application is designed. If the smallest side of a device's available screen is greater than your value here, the application runs in screen compatibility mode with no way for the user to disable it.
And I do not want compatibility mode

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use this configuration so you can include more phones:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <!-- normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

This way you support all the possible densities mentioned in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html and also add 640 if you want to support some of the newest phones (such as Samsung Galaxy S6 for example)

Answer (score -1):

```
   <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Its help for you.its filter tablets only like 7 and 10 inches.try with this once